# Uploading and Downloading Image Files with Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I want Uploading and Downloading Image Files and convert png to jpg  with Flask.
so I use PIL. I don't know uploading and downloading and convert png to jpg.

This is code

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, request
from PIL import Image

app = Flask(__name__)

def transform(pngtojpg):
    pngtojpg.save('c:/photo/result_image.jpg')
    return pngtojpg


@app.route('/')
def form():
    return """
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Transform a png to jpg</h1>

                <form action="/convert" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="img_file" />
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    """

@app.route('/convert', methods=["POST"])
def convert_view():
    file = request.files['img_file']
    if not file:
        return "No file"

    png = Image.open(file)

    result = transform(png)

    response = make_response(result)
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=result_image.jpg"
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 1):

For handling uploads have a look at the Flask documentation [Uploading Files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/). Also I can recommend using the [Flask-Uploads Plugin](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/) for handling uploads. Downloading is easy as you only need to supply a link to your image file.

For converting images from `jpg`to `png` [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.2.1) is a good choice. It is the successor of PIL.